# How to create SQL query for Fixing/filling gaps/overlapping dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I badly needed your help. Can anyone please help me how to build a query for this (see screenshot below). I'm banging my head out of this for days now.

```
CREATE TABLE PROD_TABLE(Assignment_ID   number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date);
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('1/1/2001', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/2/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/3/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/19/', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (44444,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY');


CREATE TABLE STAGING_TABLE(Assignment_ID    number, Effective_START_Date date,  Effective_END_Date date);
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('1/1/2001', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/1/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/2/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('5/4/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('5/5/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('2/2/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('2/3/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),  TO_DATE('3/19/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (30001,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),     TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (44444,   TO_DATE('3/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),     TO_DATE('4/19/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
INSERT INTO prod_table VALUES (44444,   TO_DATE('4/20/2023', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),     TO_DATE('12/31/4712', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

I have 2 tables and I need to combine them both base on the assignment_id. But my problem is if there are gaps/overlapping dates.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find overlapping date ranges between the two tables, which will multiply the number of your results a bit, then contract your start/end dates using `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```
SELECT prod_table.Assignment_ID,
       GREATEST(staging_table.effective_start_date,prod_table.effective_start_date) effective_end_date,
       LEAST(staging_table.effective_end_date,prod_table.effective_end_date) effective_end_date
  FROM PROD_TABLE,
       STAGING_TABLE
 WHERE prod_table.Assignment_ID = staging_table.Assignment_ID
   AND prod_table.effective_start_date < staging_table.effective_end_date
   AND prod_table.effective_end_date > staging_table.effective_start_date
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Man! Thank you so much for saving the my day!!! Gob bless you. And many thanks!!!!

Comment: @IMDUMB in this cade you should accept the answer please.